# Causative verb using have/has

Tags: infinitives, sentence-patterns, causative-verbs

I can understand the causative form (quite less frequently, we simply say *causal verb*) with *make* and *get* but when used with *have/has*, it sometimes makes me think differently. Of course, I can understand the construction like the following.

- I had a barber cut my hair yesterday.

In its passive form, it can be written as

- I had my hair cut yesterday (by a barber).

I can also understand that the preceding sentence (passive construction) **cannot** be rewritten as follows.

- I had cut my hair yesterday.

If it's modified in this way then both the sentences have a significant difference in meaning that I can understand.

---

The thing I don't understand properly when a bare infinitive is replaced with an infinitive in such kind of constructions, such as.

- He has his wife **cook** dinner for him.

What happens, if the bare infinitive i.e *cook* is replaced with an infinitive like the following.

- He has his wife **to cook** dinner for him.

At a glance, you will be able to understand the difference between them but for me, it's not English but it's my native language in which as far as I know there is no difference between these two sentences and even the causative construction is simply made by just using some suffixes to the main verb in a sentence. So please take it easy. Could you please expose the important difference between these preceding two sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**He has his wife cook dinner for him** means that he asks or orders his wife to cook his dinner.

**He has his wife to cook dinner for him** means something on the order of *He doesn't need to hire a cook because he has a wife who will cook his dinner for him*.

The first is causative, but the second is merely descriptive.

Comment: It means that the second example simply implies *possession* whereas the first one makes someone do something - the person wants something to be done for him. Am I wrong?

Comment: In this case, no, you're not wrong. I'm not sure whether it implies _possession_ (I assume that he doesn't **possess** (own) his wife the way he **possesses** (owns) his car), just that it's a grammatical possessive form. Sometimes it's necessary to be nit-picky about this kind of stuff.